# Tenure-track reference letters: previous supervisors versus outsiders

Tags: computer-science, united-states, recommendation-letter, tenure-track, canada

I remember reading in *The Professor Is In* that the tenure-track references should be from external members, not only your past advisors/supervisors.

That book is written aimed at social sciences, maybe, so, for Computer Science, in Canada (and the US), how important is it really?

I imagine that it would not be a dealbreaker for a rockstar, and that exactly how much impact would depend on the case/institution/competition, but what can I expect the impact to be?

Comment: Are you talking about the applications for the applications for tenure-track jobs, or for the tenure conversion application?

Comment: @aeismail For the jobs, not TT->Tenure. One problem at a time :)

Comment: I think the direct idea from the book is that the reference letters could be strengthened by including at most one from a more objective person not on your committee or not at your university. Certainly the main letters would be by those knowing you best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a lot harder to have non-advisors write letters for a tenure-track application in most STEM fields, largely because of the more direct connection between projects, funding, and supervision in STEM fields versus humanities fields.

In the applications I've reviewed as a hiring committee member in engineering, pretty much every letter came from either a PI or co-PI of a project the applicant worked on as either a graduate student or a postdoc. If there was a letter from an "external" member, I don't recall seeing it. However, it certainly wouldn't hurt if such letters were available, so long as it's a helpful letter of recommendation.

Comment: This isn't true in all of STEM.  In (pure) math, it's typical to get "external" letters.